# ffmpeg video conversion creates empty file when using php's exec()

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, exec

When I run `ffmpeg` with PHP's `exec()` function to convert a video to flv, the flv file ends up empty. Here is the code I have that does the conversion:

```
    // Set our source file
    $srcFile = "/path/to/file/".$filename."mp4";
    $destFile = "/path/to/file/".$filename;
    $ffmpegPath = "ffmpeg";

    // Create our FFMPEG-PHP class
    $ffmpegObj = new ffmpeg_movie($srcFile);

    // Save our needed variables
    $srcWidth = makeMultipleTwo($ffmpegObj->getFrameWidth());
    $srcHeight = makeMultipleTwo($ffmpegObj->getFrameHeight());
    $srcFPS = $ffmpegObj->getFrameRate();
    $srcAB = intval($ffmpegObj->getAudioBitRate()/1000);
    $srcAR = $ffmpegObj->getAudioSampleRate();

    // Call our convert using exec()
    $command = $ffmpegPath . " -i " . $srcFile . " -ar " . $srcAR . " -ab " . $srcAB . "k -f flv -s " . $srcWidth . "x" . $srcHeight . " " . $destFile . "> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &";
    exec($command);
```

Before I execute the code above, I have an mp4 file this is uploaded which is the one mentioned in the variable `$srcFile`. when uploaded, that file is not empty and I am to use it like a normal video file.

Afterwards, there will be both `filename.mp4` and `filename` (formated to `flv` video. yes, I've tried giving it an .flv extension and nothing different happens) files. `filename` ends up empty. To make sure it's running the right command, I did an `var_dump($command)` to see the command that was actually running. I got this result:

```
ffmpeg -i /path/to/file/filename.mp4 -ar 44100 -ab 70k -f flv -s 640x480 /path/to/file/filename
```

I then run `exec()` function like this

```
$output = "";
exec($command, $output);
var_dump($output);
```

and like this

```
$output = exec($command);
var_dump($output);
```

Both times, `$output` is presented as an empty array. Then, I run the `ffmpeg` command mentioned above through command line. And it worked. It created the flv file and it wasn't empty and I was able to use as a regular video file with no problems.

I also tried adding `> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &` at the end of the command and it still didn't work.

To sum up, so far, when `ffmpeg` is used to convert videos with php's `exec()`, it creates the converted as an empty. Though, if I was to take the same command used with `exec()` and use it through command line, it works perfectly fine.

I'm stumped. I've been tackling this for days and haven't really gotten anywhere. Where I going wrong? Is there a different or better way of doing this? Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you able to get simpler commands to run or does any call to `ffmpeg` result in no output? ie `$output = array(); $status = 1; exec('/path/to/ffmpeg -h 2>&1', $output, $status); var_dump($output); echo  ($status == 0) ? 'success' : 'failure';`

Comment: @cOle2 it comes back as 'success', but the output is HUGE. Not big enough to put in a comment or even the question.

Comment: Sounds like it works ok via PHP then. I'd guess there's something with your command that is not quite right. Maybe enclose your file paths in quotes in case there are special characters. If the above test code works maybe build on that until it stops working. Sorry can't be of more help.

Comment: @cOle2 So, my status, when I run the ffmpeg command, is returning 1. I don't if that changes things.

Comment: Exit codes higher than `0` mean the program exited with an error. If the simple command worked then there must be something wrong with your command. I'd try something like `$command = '"' . $ffmpegPath . '" -i ' .'"'. $srcFile . '"' . -ar ' . $srcAR . ' -ab ' . $srcAB . 'k -f flv -s ' . $srcWidth . 'x' . $srcHeight . ' "' . $destFile . '" 2>&1';`

Comment: did you ever manage to solve this? I'm having the exact same problem

Comment: @Hirvesh to be honest, I don't remember. I think we eventually scrapped PHP and moved to using Node.js, so I never needed to solve this. I think I just created the ffmpeg command, put it into a string, and ran that command. That's what the other comments suggested.

Comment: @RobAveryIV, thanks for taking the time to reply. I figured out it was just a quick in the command options and when I simplified it, it worked.